# Fatal error: Call to undefined function ldap_control_paged_result()

Tags: php, ldap

I am using LDAP in my project . I am getting following error.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function ldap_control_paged_result()
```

This was my code looks :

```
$ds=ldap_connect("162.188.10.180");  // must be a valid LDAP server!
if ($ds)
{
    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);


     $dn        = 'DC=testphp,DC=local';
     $filter    = '(|(cn=vol*)(givenname=Abd*))';
     $justthese = array('ou', 'cn', 'givenname', 'mail');
     ldap_control_paged_result($ds, 1);

     $sr = ldap_search($ds, $dn, $filter, $justthese);

     $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);

     echo $info['count'] . ' entries returned' . PHP_EOL;

    ldap_close($ds);
} else
{
    echo "<h4>Unable to connect to LDAP server.</h4>".ldap_error($ds);
}
```

Please help me to solve.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Wrong version of PHP

The function [ldap_control_paged_result](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-control-paged-result.php) is only available in php 5.4 or later - you'll need to upgrade php to a current version or use a different function.